# Python pandas data frame clean with dictionary of regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, pandas, data-science, data-cleaning

I want to clean a pandas data frame using a dictionary of regular expressions representing allowed data entry formats.

I'm trying to iterate over the input data frame so to check every row against the allowed data entry format for a given column.

If an entry doesn't meet the format allowed for the column, I want to replace it with NaN (see desired output below).

My current code gives me an error message: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'col'.

My MWE features two representative regular expressions, but for my actual data set I've got ~40.

Thanks for any help!

```
# Packages 
import pandas as pd
import re
import numpy as np 


# Input data frame 
data = {'score': [71,72,55,'a'],
        'bet': [0.260,0.380,'0.8dd',0.260]
        }
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['score', 'bet'])


# Input dictionary 
dict1 = {'score':'^\d+$', 
         'bet': '^\d[\.]\d+$'}


# Cleaning function  
def cleaner(df, dict):
    for col in df.columns:
        if col in dict: 
            for row in df.col:
                if re.match(dict[col], str(row)):
                    row = row 
                else:
                    row = np.nan
    return(df)


cleaned_df = cleaner(df1, dict1)


# ERROR MESSAGE 
# 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'col'


# Desired output 
goal_data = {'score': [71,72,55, np.nan],
        'bet': [0.260,0.380, np.nan, 0.260]
        }
goal_df = pd.DataFrame(goal_data, columns = ['score', 'bet'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a problem with your cleaning function in the if statement.
try running the following cleaner function in place of yours.

```
# Cleaning function  
def cleaner(df, dict):
    for col in df.columns:
        if col in dict.keys(): 
            for row in df.index:
                if type(re.match(dict[col], str(df[col][row]))) is re.Match:
                    df[col][row] = df[col][row] 
                    print(df[col][row])
                else:
                    df[col][row] = np.nan
    return(df)
print(cleaner(df1, dict1))
cleaned_df = cleaner(df1, dict1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `np.where(if condition, yes,else alternative)`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df1['score']=np.where(df1.score.str.match('^\d+$'),df1['score'],np.nan)
df1['bet']=np.where(df1.bet.str.match('^\d[\.]\d+$'),df1['bet'],np.nan)

score   bet
0   71  0.26
1   72  0.38
2   55  NaN
3   NaN 0.26
```